# Linux centos firewall commands not found

Tags: centos, firewalld

```
firewalld-cmd--add-service=mysql--zone=public--permanent
firewalld-cmd--add-service=http--zone=public--permanent
firewalld-cmd--add-port=80/tcp--zone=public--permanent
firewalld-cmd--reload

lamps: line 16: firewalld-cmd--add-service=mysql--zone=public--permanent: command not found
lamps: line 17: firewalld-cmd--add-service=http--zone=public--permanent: command not found
lamps: line 18: firewalld-cmd--add-port=80/tcp--zone=public--permanent: No such file or directory
lamps: line 19: firewalld-cmd--reload: command not found
```

I've tried moving all the format of the text around more - less - spaces non spaces it all just comes out with those errors
Ive tried spacing out firewalld-cmd --
and that has just achieved the same result

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `firewall-cmd` instead?

Also, there should be a space in between the program and any flags. Your commands are just incorrect/malformed.

Comment: with firewall-cmd achieves the same problem

what do you mean by program and flags?

Comment: Try this and paste the results: `firewall-cmd —reload`

Comment: usage: see firewall-cmd man page
firewall-cmd: error: unrecognized arguments: —reload

Comment: Ok - as you can see from that, `firewall-cmd` is installed. Your commands are just formatted incorrectly. I’d suggest reading the man pages to see exactly how to format them properly. You should have appropriate spaces between the different flags.

Comment: sudo firewall-cmd --reload, 
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http